# all possible time delta combinations in python

Tags: python, time, combinations, duration

I have a time period from 9:00 till 22:00 and I need to list all possible durations with a step of 30 minutes within this period. E.g.

```
9:00 - 9:30
9:00 - 10:00
9:00 - 10:30
...
21:00 - 22:00
21:30 - 22:00
```

I've googled and found itertools.combinations() for numbers but nothing comparable for dates

Comment: Loop over all possible starting times, and for each of them, all possible ending times? Which specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.